# Retrieve frequency R

Tags: r, frequency

I have a dataset with 7 columns that contain both numerical as string data. I want to get the frequency of 1 and 0 of a certain column (Familiarity), grouped by a different column (Subject).

Subject contains the following type of data: s120, s121 etc.
Familiarity contains the following type of data: 1, 0

I have tried the following:

```
freq <- dat %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  sum(dat$Familiarity==0)
```

But this gives me the following error:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Does this mean I would have to convert my entire dataframe in order to make this work? Or how can I fix this.

Comment: I have solved it by using the following:

`freq1 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  summarize(sum(Familiarity==0))`

Comment: But would still like to know why the above does not work :( !

Comment: Because `sum` is not a `dplyr` function, and you are piping `dplyr` functions, where calculations like frequencies are correctly put inside `summarize` (or `tally`, in this case); like `dat %>% group_by(Subject) %>% tally(Familiarity==0)`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the summarize portion as well as naming your new variable.
Does this workfor you.

```
freq <- dat %>%
    group_by(Subject) %>% 
    summarize(Number_of_1s = sum(Familiarity))
```